# Is it possible to use an append function in a return statement for purposes of a recursive procedure in Python

Tags: python, return, append

Is it possible to use an append function in a return statement?

If I say:

```
def test_func(n):
a=[1,2,3]
a.append(n)
return a

print test_func(6)
```

I get:

```
[1,2,3,6]
```

But if I say:

```
def test_func(n):
a=[1,2,3]
return a.append(n)

print test_func(6)
```

I get:

```
None
```

The reason I want this is because I want to write a recursive function that calls itself until the base case is reached, but for each cycle it executes, I want to append that result to a list.

So I want to try something along the lines of: return a.append(func(new_input))

Basically, am I doing something wrong in the above example? Or is it not possible to append in the return statement.

Comment: Appending returns None. What's the problem with having two lines?

Comment: Agree: methods that mutates the sequence always return ˋNone`.  For instance: `append`, `extend`, `sort`…

Comment: You **are** appending in the return statement, so obviously it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace `append` by a call to `__iadd__`:

```
def test_func(n):
    a = [1, 2, 3]
    return a.__iadd__([n])
```

This should work.

But I don't understand why you don't use your first idea.

Answer (score 0):

The append function does not return any value but updates the existing list.

In your first implementation you are returning the list **a**, in your second implementation you are returning the return value of the function append (that always return None).

So, the answer is: it is not possible the function append be in the return statement and works the way you want.